# How do I save NSUserDefaults when dictionary key has a Null value

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, nsdictionary, nsuserdefaults

I have a project using [SwiftForms](https://github.com/ortuman/SwiftForms).
There is a navbar button that performs an function to send the info in the textFields to NSUserDefaults. But the app crashes if I have an empty textField, but data is saved when all fields are filled out. Do I just add a check in the function to look for `NSNull`?

```
func submit(_: UIBarButtonItem!) {
    let message = self.form.formValues()
    //message is [String : AnyObject]
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
    userDefaults.setObject(message as Dictionary, forKey: "theMessage")
    print("\n Message Saved! \n")
    print(message)
}
```

This is the error I get when I click save and don't fill out any fields and the app crashes:

```
Attempt to set a non-property-list object {
    birthday = "<null>";
    job = "<null>";
    lastName = "<null>";
    name = "<null>";
    segmented = "<null>";
    stepper = 20;
    textview = "<null>";
} as an NSUserDefaults/CFPreferences value for key theMessage
```

This is what I get when I fill out all the fields - No crash

```
 --- Message Saved! --- 

["segmented": 1, "job": Job, "lastName": Last, "birthday": 2016-07-01 22:00:12 +0000, "textview": Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semperac, vestibulum at eros., "stepper": 22, "name": First]
```

Comment: Post the code where you are adding the values in your dictionary.

Comment: Unlike a Swift dictionary, an NSDictionary can't contain nulls. Your `formValues` function should return a dictionary without optionals; either put "", `NSNull` in the empty values or probably even better, omit the keys where there is no value.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`formValues` returns `NSNull` for empty values which can't be saved in `NSDictionary` as noted by *Paulw11*.

You can use this function to filter it.

```
let filtered = message.filter({!$1.isKindOfClass(NSNull)}).reduce([:]) { ( dic , e) -> [String:AnyObject] in
            var dic = dic
            dic[e.0 as! String] = e.1
            return dic
        }
```

and then save the `filtered` in `userDefaults`

Comment: oh boy, ill have to go through that code snippet and dissect it to understand what is going on. I appreciate your help. I had started with adding
 `for (key,value) in message {
            if value is NSNull {
              message[key] = "" as String
            }}`

Comment: Thats also a valid way , Did you try the snippet , if it worked   please accept the answer.

Comment: Answer accepted, would you mind explaining the closure a bit so that other noobies including myself can understand the high order functions and closures a bit more?

Comment: @Ken , I found this post which has filter with reduce example , http://arsenkin.com/Swift-map-Swift-reduce-and-Swift-filter-functions.html
Please tell me of any specific thats not clear to you :)

Answer (score 0):

The Swift class is now `UserDefaults` (`NSUserDefaults` is an Objective-C class). However, it doesn't change the fact that Swift cannot store dictionaries with `nil` values in that class. Therefore, simply archive the dictionary as `Data` first.

```
var someDictionary: [String: String?] = ["a": nil, "b": "beta"]

do {

    let data = try NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: someDictionary, requiringSecureCoding: false)
    UserDefaults.standard.set(data, forKey: "someKey")

} catch let error {
    print(error)
}
```

And to retrieve the dictionary, simply unarchive it:

```
if let def = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "someKey") as? Data,
    let d = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(def) as? [String: String?] {
    print(d) // ["a": nil, "b": Optional("beta")]
}
```

In the example above, the `try?` keyword handles the result as an optional. If you wish to handle errors, use the do-try-catch pattern:

```
if let def = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "someKey") as? Data {

    do {

        if let d = try NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(def) as? [String: String?] {
            print(d) // ["a": nil, "b": Optional("beta")]
        }

    } catch {
        print(error)
    }

}
```

You can write any object to disk as long as it conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol.